# Update many columns automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I want to update many columns without having to manually type the `set = , set = ,  set =`   syntax many times if there were 100 over columns.

How do I update all columns automatically?

```
update table1
set t1.col1 = t2.col1, t1.col2 = t2.col2 ...........
from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2
```

I tried to use `info.schema` to get all the columns name as string and save inside a `@variable`.
but could not find ways to use the `@variable` as part of an update statement.

For example:

```
@variable is  nvarchar (max)

@variable =       t1.col1 = t2.col1, t1.col2 = t2.col2, t1.col3 = t2.col3
```

and so on......

Tried to execute an SQL variable
execution:

```
@sql_query = 'update set' + @variable +
from table1 as t1 inner join table 2 as t2
```

Comment: You could consider dynamic SQL...

Comment: SQL-Server Management Studio can generate an UPDATE query for every table.

Comment: Excel also helps with constructing large column number SQL statements, especially when column from different tables have the same names.

Comment: In first glance your best solution is to hire a DBA, since it seems like you are looking for the lazy solution instead for the DBA solution! Unless you have a `technical` reason for this requirement, request to have shorter text in the query is not a professional request but a laziness request! You can dynamically build the query string once (using a query or using excel) but use the text as direct query and not as dynamic query unless there is a reason for this (for example the columns which you need to update change dynamically) - `a DBA goal should be performance and not shorter text`